# how to do to get data from settings and send to this fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, mpandroidchart, data-transfer

Good morning, I would like a window to open in SettingsFragment with the option to choose a csv text file, after selecting the file, this data is sent to the ChartFragment and the data is drawn in the form of a graph. Structure MVVM. So far I did it, but I don't know how to end it, please help. This is my code

SettingsFragment:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    private val SETTINGS_DEBUG = "SETTINGS_DEBUG"

    private val resolver by lazy { requireContext().contentResolver }

    private val myViewModel by viewModels<ChartViewModel>()
    
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        
    val myPref: Preference? = findPreference("load_csv_file") as Preference?
        myPref?.onPreferenceClickListener = Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
            try {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                intent.type = "text/*"
                startActivity(intent)
            }catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.d(SETTINGS_DEBUG, exc.message.toString())
            }
            myViewModel.csvResultLiveData
            true
        }
    }
}
```

Chartfragment:

```
class ChartFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentChartBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val CHART_DEBUG = "CHART_DEBUG"

    private val lineChartVm: ChartViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentChartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        Log.d(CHART_DEBUG, "transfer date successfully")

        lineChartVm.csvResultLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { csvLines ->
            // do something with csvLines, a List<String>
                Log.d(CHART_DEBUG, "transfer date successful")

                val newEntries = csvLines.map { line -> toEntry(line) }.groupingBy { entry -> entry.x }
                    .reduce { _, accumulator, element -> if (accumulator.y > element.y) accumulator else element }.values
                val lineChart = binding.lineChart
                val vl = LineDataSet(newEntries.toList().take(4000), "cost")
                vl.setDrawValues(false)
                vl.setDrawFilled(true)
                vl.lineWidth = 1.5f
                vl.fillColor = R.color.gray
                vl.fillAlpha = R.color.red
                vl.setDrawCircles(false)
                lineChart.data = LineData(vl)
                lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
                lineChart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)
                lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
                lineChart.isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
                lineChart.isScaleYEnabled = false
                lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
        }
        
        val markerView = CustomMarker(activity?.applicationContext, R.layout.marker_view)
        binding.lineChart.marker = markerView
        
        return binding.root
    }
    private fun toEntry(line: String): Entry {
        val split = line.split(";")
        val time = split[1]
        // idx 01234 012345 l:5 lub 6
        // val 84504 165959
        // 0, 3 - 845
        val secondsStartIdx = time.length - 2
        val minutesStartIdx = time.length - 4
        val hoursStartIdx = (time.length - 6).coerceAtLeast(0)

        val hour = time.substring(hoursStartIdx, hoursStartIdx + time.length - 4)
        val minutest = time.substring(minutesStartIdx, minutesStartIdx + 2)
        val seconds = time.substring(secondsStartIdx, secondsStartIdx + 2)

        val newTime =
            hour.toFloat() * 10000 + (minutest.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt() * 100 + (seconds.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt()
        return Entry(newTime, split[2].toFloat())
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**vote up**confent///post///materials =////fun

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).